# Keyboard shortcut for selection field

Tags: selection, keyboard

In our (desktop) application, we have two different families of selection fields. Some can open a **dropdown** dialog (combo boxes, date fields which open a calendar in the drop down), and the others can open a selection **dialog** instead. The latter looks like this:

[image]

For the dropdown fields, we use *ArrowDown* as a keyboard shortcut to open the dropdown popup.

For the fields which open a dialog, we're yet **unnsure which keyboard shortcut to use to open the dialog**. The button which opens the dialog *cannot* be reached with tabbing (all our fields have only one component that can be reached by TAB, the next TAB will always leave the field).

What's the appropriate keyboard shortcut in this case?
Whould we use *ArrowDown* as well, or rather some other shortcut such as *Enter*?

Comment: Why can't it be reached by tabbing? How do keyboard-only users use this application?

Comment: The field consists of two widgets (text and button), but should behave like it's one widget. Users can navigate through fields with TAB, but we like the idea of consistently jumping to the next widget with each TAB, and not jumping around in a widget's subcomponents. All functionality the widget offers is thus reachable by keyboard shortcuts, in order to be fully usable keyboard-only.

Comment: Well how about as a compromise that the TAB jumps from widget to widget, but once you're actually within a widget *and using it* (such as typing in the field) then the TAB will jump between components of that widget. Similar to how some navigation menus work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One action – one shortcut. Although the results are different, still the action is the same: `Open`. So *ArrowDown* is good choice for this.

Some users probably would be confused a bit by watching dots instead the more habitual triangle. But here reasoning by analogy could work, as the layout of the `open dialog […]` control  is similar to `select [▼]` control.